# How can i change the corresponding X-Axis Label for a given point in 'iplot' of python

Tags: python, data-visualization, iplots

[This is the image which i have generated using iplot in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRxuR.png)

How can i show the corresponding data element name , when i am using iplot function .
I have used the following commmand to create the plot

```
data_f = pd.DataFrame({'Third':val , 'Fourth':val2 , 'Sixth':val3  }  )
data_f.iplot( )
```

Here val,val2,val3 are the Pandas.Series and the corresponding columns are 'Third' , 'Fourth' , 'Sixth' , and for these columns corresponding to the roll number of each student, i want to plot the graph using iplot , showing roll number instead of series of [1,2,3,.. ] in x -axis 
The corresponding roll numbers are present as series as roll_series.

Thank you in advance for help

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to put all the series in a dataframe and plot as below.

```
# Create series val, val1, val3 and roll_num
val = np.random.randn(10)
val2 = np.random.randn(10)
val3= np.random.randn(10)
roll_num = np.linspace(start=1001,stop=1010,num=10)

# Create dataframe from above series
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': val, 'val2': val2, 'val3': val3, 'roll_num':roll_num})
df.head(2)

# Plot using iplot() where x-axis now shows student roll number 
df.iplot(x='roll_num', y=['val', 'val2', 'val3'], xTitle='Student Roll Number',yTitle='Score',title='Class Scores')
```

[Plot with student roll number on x-axis using iplot()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSXqD.png)